# mupx: Timed out while waiting for handshake

Tags: meteor, ssh, meteor-up

Haven't encountered this until today when I was redeploying my meteor app using mupx I got this error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake
    at null._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:138:17)
```

Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check you IP address in mup.json, and use your internal IP address (like 192.168.xxx.xxx) instead public IP.